# How to save data from API in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have Comment model relationship with User

**Like this Model**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()
    point = models.CharField()
```

**Serializer**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ['comment', 'type', 'point']
```

From here I already get the API response, to save in the comment model

```
def save_response_data(data):
    # here validate...
    json_data = {}
    # I want the user instance that is making the request
    serializer = CommentSerializer(data=json_data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()

    return json_data
```

**views** request api

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    ...
    ...

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=...)
    
    # Overwrite create method
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserViewSet, self).create(request, args, kwargs)
        
        # Currently, this is how I am obtaining the user who makes the request
        user_id = request.user.id
        # Simple queryset build payload to send api
        payload = build_payload(user_id)

        response = requests.post(url, data=payload) 

        data = response.json()

        save_response_data(data)
```

I want the user instance that is making the request

I tried to do it with signals but it doesn't work, any idea or comment, it would be helpful

Comment: Can you share the code for the view that catches the request?

Comment: @HuLuViCa I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

hi i use APIView and with that i can access auth user

```
class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.user
        ...
        request.data['user']=user
        CommentSerializer(request.data)
```